# IS there any way to apply trim on any function before aggregation in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a field which contains URLs like:

```
- /home/search
- /home/search/
- /home/search{space}
- /home/review/
- /home/review
```

and when i am applying aggregation on this field, i am getting the count for all of these separately.
But i want the count as two fields only..
for 
/home/search (contains all three)
and /home/review (contains both)

Can someone please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to reindex your URLs and make use of [Trim Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-trim-tokenfilter.html)
to remove trailing spaces and [Pattern Replace Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) to get rid of trailing slashes.

**Trim Token Filter**

> The `trim` token filter trims the whitespace surrounding a token.

**Pattern Replace Token**

> Filter The `pattern_replace` token filter allows
>   to easily handle string replacements based on a regular expression.
>   The regular expression is defined using the `pattern` parameter, and
>   the replacement string can be provided using the `replacement`
>   parameter (supporting referencing the original text, as explained
>   [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String))).

When you're done with it, your URLs should come back as you expect.